# raw buffer from registry javascript

Tags: node.js, windows, registry, buffer

I am using a [windows-registry](https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node) and I am having this [issue](https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node/issues/44) (when reading file with äüö chars).

This guy mentions "If i return the raw buffer and use iconv to convert from "ISO-8859-1" to "UTF-8" i get the correct characters" So I am wondering if any of you with better understanding what's happening can explain to me if i can "return raw buffer" with JS only or with using this library. Or can I do something else?

There is also this nice man that suggested a [fix](https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node/compare/master...RupW:issue-44)

Comment: At first, the post must contain all the relevant code to reproduce the problem, also the problem must be described in the post itself. Secondly, what has this Windows stuff has to do with JavaScript?

Comment: I need to read windows registry file with javascript. And I am wondering how to do it. Library i linked does it but not very good("ÄÜÖ). So I am asking for some clarity so i can understand whats happening there, more specifically the comment suggesting to get raw buffer and then convert